# How to avoid displaying directory path in url?

Tags: api, apache, url, url-rewriting, serve

I set up a little Apache2 server on a Raspberry PI4. Now I’m looking for a way to hide the real directory path displayed in the URL. I read around that you should deal with a file called .htaccess but, I don’t even know what to actually look for on the internet. How can I display an arbitrary url in the address bar of the browser, Hiding file extension like .php and file path?

Comment: Stackoverflow is a site for _specific_ advice for a clearly outlined problem, not so much basic advice. Also, Apache httpd doesn't show the "real directory path", but some virtual path for whatever resources you organize in the directories below a certain root directory. This question is a lot too broad to lead to answers that stackoverflow is built for (see [help/on-topic]). Consider editing your question, provide a [mcve], and make sure it's about programming more than configuration. Currently you're asking for documentation pointers - which is off-topic.

Comment: I edited the post. Let me know if it’s ok or I’ll delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make rewrite rules in an Apache config file, a .htaccess file for example. One way you could achieve this is to create re-write rules in a .htaccess file. Use to below link to test your rewrite rules, then once you have that part working implement on your live apache installation.

https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/